# update column with := using variable name

Tags: r, data.table

I'm trying to update a column in a data.table, however I'm having trouble referencing the column name with a variable:

```
dt = data.table(a = 1:10, b = 1:10)
nm = 'a'
dt[ , get(nm) := get(nm) + 1]
```

> Error in get(nm) : object 'a' not found

And if I try `dt[ , nm := get(nm) + 1]` I get a new column `nm`.

What I want is

```
     a  b
 1:  2  1
 2:  3  2
 3:  4  3
 4:  5  4
 5:  6  5
 6:  7  6
 7:  8  7
 8:  9  8
 9: 10  9
10: 11 10
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here `get` returns the `value`.  In the `lhs` of `:=`, we just need to extract the column name string.  For that just wrap it with `()`

```
dt[ , (nm) := get(nm) + 1]
```

Technically, `.SDcols` would be the preferred way to specify the columns of interest in `data.table`

```
dt[, (nm) := .SD[[1]] + 1, .SDcols = nm]
```

here, the `[[` is used to extract the `vector`.

if there are more columns,

```
dt[, (nm) := lapply(.SD, `+`, 1), .SDcols = nm]
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
library(data.table)
upcols <- c('a','b')
dt[, (upcols) := lapply(.SD, function(x) x +1), .SDcols = upcols]
```

In case you want only 'a' to be updated, delete 'b' from the upcols vector.